# How to keep chrome running actively in a different macOS Space?

Tags: google-chrome, spaces

When switching away from a Space with an active chrome window it freezes. That makes sense for many scenarios - but is there a way to change that behavior either permanently or for a specific window?  I have audio running that I want to hear but keep the window out of my working area in a different Space.

I'm on Catalina 10.15.7 with latest chrome Version 97.0.4692.99.

Comment: Can't repro. Chrome keeps playing whatever Space it's in. What OS, what version Chrome?

Comment: @Tetsujin. updated the OP with macOS and chrome versions